# Does suggesting use of a web application as a solution count as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48106411/7032856), is it forbidden to suggest using a web page as a solution, or is it spamming?

The full answer (minus the actual link) reads:

> I created an online, easy-to-use in-browser python to exe converter. Link here: [...]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I see (already?) 3 answers linking to it.

Comment: .... Can't help noticing the good citizens of Stack Overflow retaliated by downvoting [that poster's scant rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8383279/rotir-noir?tab=reputation) into oblivion.

Comment: @usr2564301 The reputation says 6, but the data and the graph say 41... and the user has the commentator badge.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: the dip is too recent to be visible in the graph. Badges are forever (famously, even if one acquired it illegitimate!). There has been *one* upvote since the denouément – possibly a pity-vote, and it wasn't mine.

Comment: I don't believe that [the -100 reputation penalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/288751)  for having a spam flag validated against one of your posts is shown in the reputation history to other mortals. Now, because rep can't go below 1, the user is set to just 1 rep. If the user gets an upvote after that, their rep goes up as normal even if they didn't have enough rep to fulfill the original penalty. Also, you can get the commentator badge for commenting on your own posts I believe. @wizzwizz4

Comment: Looks like I have a red flag on it. ;p

Answer (score 28):

**Answer**: Not at all if it conforms with the requirements here (on Stack Overflow).

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) pretty tells it all:

> Here are some specific behaviors to avoid - even with the best of intentions, these will nearly always result in your posts being flagged as spam:
>
> - **Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.** Folks will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem; if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.
> - **Don't tell - show!** The best way to avoid being seen as a snake-oil salesman is to demonstrate a solution rather than simply asserting the problem can be solved.
> - **Don't include links except to *support* what you've written.** Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer. See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/350567)

I personally wouldn't consider *any* suggestion of off-site resource as spam, provided it meets the following criteria:

1. **Disclosure of affiliation.** Be it basic or full, as long as you make it clear whether you're affiliated with the product you're suggesting, that's fine. People can then judge whether you're an intentional spammer instead of guessing headlessly (and probably start flagging if there's a few of such promotions that raises suspicion). There are some very famous sites in every subject that don't need disclosure when linked to, like Super User or Server Fault. When you're unsure if people know it, or if the site contains primarily user-generated content (like GitHub, YouTube or Blogspot), it's always good to tell people whether you're affiliated.
2. **Accompanied with proper explanation** *why* and *how* it will be useful towards solving the problem. Anyway, whatever you write in an answer is required to be an honest attempt to answer the question. If it's unclear *how* it solves the problem, it's likely be considered NAA for being a link-only answer very quickly, or worse, attract red flags.
3. **Appears in a reasonable number.** If such suggestions appear in tens of answers, that'd be considered *overt*, thus (probably) spam.

I (personally) have a few more things to check before determining whether it's spam:

4. **The linked site has no spam record reported by [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey).** This is almost never the case for an honest attempt to answer the question. [Our team](https://charcoal-se.org/people) will be especially careful if a post is caught by Smokey. Most sites with known spam history will be caught and recorded, and is more likely to be considered as spam if it appears further.
5. (Additional stuff) **Possible malware.** A site is always taken seriously if it has the potential of containing malware. [Thanks to Warren P](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361453/does-suggesting-use-of-a-web-application-as-a-solution-count-as-spam#comment546122_361454).

This answer applies not only to web-apps, but every suggestion of off-site resource.

---

For the post that you give as example, here's my analysis:

1. (Help page) Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.

   It's hard to tell. Given that the user has posted at least 3 of them, with highly similar wording, I think it's a bit too much. [2 could be a limitation](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/why-is-this-spam-flag-declined#comment6281_2295).
2. (Help page) Don't tell - show!

   Obviously it's not conforming this rule. The three answers is nothing more than a link. My comment in your image reads "*Even if it's not spam, it's NAA for being link-only*".
3. Don't include links except to *support* what you've written.

   Same as above. The link is not a supportive material, but almost the whole answer.
4. Disclosure of affiliation.

   Good job on this in the first sentence: "*I wrote...*".
5. Accompanied with proper explanation

   Apparently there's no explanation at all. The whole answer is kinda "you can use it".
6. Appears in a reasonable number.

   Again as above, I believe [2 at most is acceptable](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/why-is-this-spam-flag-declined#comment6281_2295) even though it's related. (A moderator cleared all the spam flags so the user wasn't penalized).
7. Not sure what adverb to use here, but Smokey [has already recorded](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=py2exe.net&commit=Search) `py2exe.net`.

So given all above, I would choose to flag it as spam as I really did for its excessive promotional behavior.

8. Possible malware. Who guarantees the generated `.exe` isn't malicious?

Comment: Suggested 4.  If the provided off site link is something that could be a malware vector, please vote to close and flag the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## The official definition for using the spam flag is:

"Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).".

By that very narrow definition this does not qualify for the `spam` flag as they disclose their affiliation.

That does not make it a good answer by any means and should be down voted and deleted for other very reasonable reasons.

Included in the [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) link it clearly states that these link only answers are not acceptable..

> Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are
>   not a substitute for including information in your answer itself, and
>   links should always be directly relevant to a part of your answer. See
>   also:
>   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

So *"spam"*, no, low quality, down vote/delete worthy, yes.

Answer (score 0):

### What if it answers the question?

I'd say a suggested web application that directly solves the problem is **never spam**.

Although it's probably almost always **a link-only answer ("not an answer") that should be deleted**, since it's entirely dependent on the site remaining active. No amount of explanation can change that, unless the gist of the code on the website appears in the answer itself, in which case the link is probably more just additional information for an otherwise appropriate answer.

Although in this case **the question is probably off topic**, since it's roughly asking for a tool recommendation, for which all the answers will largely be links elsewhere.

Spam gets punished quite heavily on Stack Overflow, which should be reserved for users actually acting maliciously, not for a single well-intentioned (albeit misguided) attempt to answer a question.

### What if it doesn't answer the question?

If the user is posting such recommendations on questions where it's hard to argue that it's a direct answer to the question, that's probably spam (but I might still opt for not-an-answer if the intention seems good).

### What if the user keeps doing it?

If there's a pattern of a user posting such answers, flagging for a moderator to get involved could be an appropriate course of action (assuming the user hasn't managed to get themselves banned in the mean time).

### How much has the user contributed?

I think this is also an important question.

For a first post, I might be more inclined to flag it as spam (if it's hard to quickly tell whether the site seems legitimate, and also obviously for something that's obviously not legitimate).

But when the user has made a few reasonable posts to date (like in this case), a recommendation seems a whole lot more likely to be well-intentioned, so I'd tend towards a not-an-answer flag.

Comment: This particular web application may do malicious things.  How do I know what else is linked into that .exe binary it provides to me other than my code and how do I know the python runtime it bundles is untainted. Here, download a giant binary.  Run it on your computers.  Couldn't possibly include a nested bitcoin miner, keylogger, or meltdown attack, could it?  There isn't a malware choice on SO.  So Spam is the closest think I'd pick.

Comment: @WarrenP Potential malicious sites seems like a problem with just about any link to a site that isn't particularly well-known (or even those that are, for that matter). Of course downloading an exe does increase your risk quite a bit, but focusing on that seems like missing the forest for the trees (since the question literally asks for something that produces an exe). If it's **obviously** malicious, a spam flag is appropriate; if it's an actual answer to the question that **might** be malicious, a downvote and/or comment (+ NAA flag, as mentioned in my answer) seems more appropriate.

Comment: Out of my own experience: flagging link-only answers as "not an answer" often gets declined - better use "very low quality" instead.

Comment: "What if it answers the question?" If it is a valid answer to a question, then that question is asking for a tool, library, or other off-site resource.

Comment: @usr2564301 Possibly, but not necessary. For a question like "how do I do X", one can say "here's some code that does X" or "here's a link to a resource that does X". If the question's explicitly asking for an offsite resource, then yes, it's off topic.

Comment: And if it's something like this that provides binaries of unknown provenance, it should be flagged and removed by any means necessary.